# initWithFrame faster than view.frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uiview

I'm just curious, when it comes to initializing `UIView`s; I notice that when I call the instance constructor `-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`, the primitive constructor `-(id)init` is never actually called, meaning that I would have to initialize instance variables in both constructors. Is this meant to be an optimization strategy such that calling `-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` is computationally "faster" (encourage better performance) than calling `UIView *view = [UIView new]; view.frame = frame;`? Is the initWithFrame option quicker than creating a new instance and assigning its frame manually? I actually prefer to do the latter to maintain programmatic consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's simply that `initWithFrame` is the *designated initializer* of `UIView` (from the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)):

> **Discussion**
>
> The new view object must be inserted into the view
>   hierarchy of a window before it can be used. If you create a view
>   object programmatically, this method is the designated initializer for
>   the UIView class. Subclasses can override this method to perform any
>   custom initialization but must call super at the beginning of their
>   implementation.